# Как открыть фрагмент из адаптера RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть адаптер, который заполняет `RecyclerView`. Прочитав форумы понял что обработчик нажатий необходимо сделать тоже в адаптере. Как открыть фрагмент по нажатию на элемент `RecyclerView`?

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Вот это не работает, пишет `cannot resolve method getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: На самом деле надо бы не в адаптере обрабатывать... А создать интерфейс, реализовать его в хозяине адапетера (активити/фрагмент) передавать и хранить его экземпляр в адаптере и вызывать его метод в момент клика. Тогда код будет выполняться в актвити/фрагменте и там фрагменты уже и менять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вот это не работает, пишет `cannot resolve method getFragmentManager()`.

И правильно пишет, так как в классе адаптера (и его суперклассе) нет подобного метода.

Можно пробросить нажатие на пункт списка в активити, а уже оттуда делать то, что Вы хотите.

1. Объявляете интерфейс:

   ```
   public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
       void onClick();
   }
   ```
2. Реализуете этот интерфейс в классе активити:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

       ...

       @Override
       public void onClick() {

       }
   }
   ```
3. В адаптере добавляете поле:

   ```
   private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener mClickListener;
   ```
4. При создании адаптера устанавливаете обработчик нажатия:

   ```
   public MyAwesomeAdapter(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener clickListener) {
       mClickListener = clickListener;
   }
   ```
5. При клике на айтем, в адаптере вызываете коллбэк:

   ```
   if (mClickListener != null) {
       mClickListener.onClick();
   }
   ```

PS. Разумеется, в метод `onClick()` можно добавить необходимые параметры.

Comment: немного не понятно про 4 пункт и 5 пункт, не понимаю где конкретно вызывать, может у вас есть пример исходника? мне необходимо при нажатии на элемент card view открыть новый фрагмент и необходимо вытащить position из адаптера. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Что Вам непонятно в 4 пункте? Про 5-й: В методе `onBindViewHolder(...)` адаптера вешаете на холдер `View.OnClickListener` и в `onClick(...)` вызываете коллбэк. Так же можно передать позицию, для этого, в 1-м пункте добавляете в метод аргумент типа `int`, а при вызове этого метода передаете в него `position`. Половина примера [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/7129209).

Comment: спасибо, получилось!