# Как из адаптера передать клик в активити?

Tags: android

Нашел в этот вариант, но не совсем понимаю то значит 4 пункт.

[Как открыть фрагмент из адаптера RecyclerView?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667454/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-recyclerview)

Comment: Вы бы привели пример своего кода и что у вас не получается. Вот посмотрите еще [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775980/263405).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно при создании адаптера передавать реализацию твоего интерфейса, тоесть ты будешь описывать то что случится когда ты вызовешь описанный метод в адаптере.

Comment: У меня при создании экземпляра адаптеру передаются в него данные, я же не могу использовать 2 конструктора одновременно? mAdaptor = new MyAdaptor(mDataSet);

Comment: if (mClickListener != null) {
    mClickListener.onClick();
}

Вот в этом условие, где оно заполняеться, что не равно null